# MacOSX Yosemite: Using R in the Terminal - a gfortran error

Tags: r, command-line, osx-yosemite, osx-yosemite-beta

I just recently updated to the newest build of MacOSX Yosemite (Yosemite Beta Version 3 - September 15th 2014 Update).  R was working fine in Yosemite before this new update, but now I am getting this error when I run from the command line:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0/4.8.3/libgfortran.3.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/r/3.1.1/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/lib/libR.dylib
  Reason: image not found
[1]    80010 trace trap  R
```

It's a `gfortran` error I presume -- I've re-installed X-Code, gcc4.9 (etc.), and gfortran (I use homebrew to manage my packages and tried to compile from package too) to no avail.

I haven't noticed any other applications or programs that have stopped working.

Here's the real kicker for me: R from within R-Studio works like a charm.

This wouldn't be a big deal, but I use R from the command line in a couple of my data analysis pipelines.

Any ideas how to fix this error? Googling around has got me nowhere.

#### UPDATES:

- This isn't such a big deal to go back and install Mavericks -- I was running both for a while, but Yosemite doesn't have any large problems with the new beta updates.  I can still use R via RStudio, just glibfortran is not talking to R in my terminal.  I'm just concerned for scripts that call on R at the command line.
- Doesn't appear to be a homebrew issue as when I compile gfortran from source I get the same error.

#### FINAL UPDATE:

#### This error was fixed in the newest Yosemite Beta release Version 4 on September 30th 2014.

Comment: Honestly, I think the easiest thing to do would be to go back to Mavericks. Surely if its a genuine issue between R and Yosemite the only fix will be to wait for R Core to test on Yosemite themselves and fix it. In the meantime, why make your life more difficult than it needs to be?

Comment: I'm suspecting this is more likely a Homebrew issue and not an R issue.

Comment: Would be good to add that as an answer then accept it (points! and it closes an open question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATES:

This isn't such a big deal to go back and install Mavericks -- I was running both for a while, but Yosemite doesn't have any large problems with the new beta updates. I can still use R via RStudio, just glibfortran is not talking to R in my terminal. I'm just concerned for scripts that call on R at the command line.

Doesn't appear to be a homebrew issue as when I compile gfortran from source I get the same error.

FINAL UPDATE:

This error was fixed in the newest Yosemite Beta release Version 4 on September 30th 2014.